# How to clone elements and generate dynamic ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am cloning some form elements and want to generate for them dynamic ids so I can acces their content later on, but I don't really know how to do that, I'm a noob with Jquery/Javascript, by the way.

My html:

```
<tr>
<td>
<label for="ability">Ability</label><br>
    <div id="rank_ability" name="rank_ability">
        <select name="ability" id="ability">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="hexa">Test</option>
        </select><br>
        <label for="range_ability_min">Range:</label>
        <input type="textbox" name="range_ability_min" id="range_ability_min" class="small_text" value="0"  /> - 
        <input type="textbox" mame="range_ability_max" id="range_ability_max" class="small_text" value="0"  /><br>
    </div>
    <a href="#page" class="rank_clone">Add Ability</a><br><br>
</td>
</tr>
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var element, ele_nr, new_id;
    $('.rank_clone').click( function() {
        element = $(this).prev();
        ele_nr = $('div[name="'+element.attr('name')+'"]').length;

        new_id = element.attr('name') + ele_nr;

        element.clone().attr('id', new_id).attr('name', new_id).insertAfter(element);
    });
});
```

I setup a jsfiddle with what I got here: http://jsfiddle.net/xjoo4q96/

Now, I am using .prev() to select the element to clone which leads to those repeated 1 in the id/name attributes, how could I select it in another way (to mention: I really need to use 'this' because I need this little script in like 3 places, so I don't want to write it for an element with a specific id/class).

Also, I am counting only the element with the base name attribute so .lenght yelds 1 all the time, how would I go around counting all of them ? I guess I have to place them in another div or something but I don't know how would I go around couting them even then.

And, at last, how would I go around changing all the name/id attributes of the  elements I have in the div ?

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching already with the wrong name, since it still has the number attached. So delete it first, search for element which have a name attribute starting with this name and then use this base name to create a new one.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var element, ele_nr, new_id, base_name;
    $('.rank_clone').click( function() {
        element = $(this).prev();

        base_name = element.attr('name').replace(/[0-9]/g, '');

        ele_nr = $('div[name^="'+base_name+'"]').length;

        new_id = base_name + ele_nr;

        element.clone().attr('id', new_id).attr('name', new_id).insertAfter(element);
    });
});
```

And to answer your last question: you can not go around changing all ids of inner elements, it would be invalid HTML. In principal you can do the same with every id, like adding a number. If you have to do the same with all the name attributes depends on what you want to do exactly. If you have to distinguish between the first and second input, which I suggest, you have to change them too.

Comment: Thanks for this, it works like a charm and your idea is great.

Comment: About that last part, I want to get the values from every input and then ajax them to a php file and get the results. So basically I just have to assign every value to a variable. I guess I can use something like $('div #rank_ability1 #ability') to select them and it should be fine. I need to call it a day right now, so I will see tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

you can put the template in a hidden div like `#tmpl`, then clone and set the `id` attr, e.g.

```
$('#tmpl').children().first().clone().appendTo('#target').attr('id', 'the_generated_id');
```

#### Update

Demo of the template way: http://jsfiddle.net/xjoo4q96/1/, though it would be quite easy to adjust the code to clone the first component that already existed.

BTW, principally, `id` should be unique, thus the sub-element in the cloned component should use other attribute, like `class` or certain `data-` attribute, like those used in the updated fiddle.

Also you might want to call `event.preventDefault()` as you're clicking an `<a>`

Comment: This is an excellent answer, and I would +1 the answer if you edited the OP's jsFiddle to demonstrate that your answer works. (I'll keep watching this post, with my finger on the +1 key...)

Comment: @gibberish, fiddle updated to demo the template part.

Comment: I actually dig more the one that I selected from above, I just feel that it's more straightforward and easy to understand (noob friendly). Thank you for your answer aswell.

Answer (score 0):

try to use cloneJs, it's clone ids, names input, and parametre inside functions ids of input must be like id_foo_1, id_foo_2 ,,,, and name be like inputName[0][foo], inputName[1][foo]  https://github.com/yagami271/clonejs